# Getting an Application-defined or Object-defined error in VBA using Validation

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, offset

I am trying to get the address of a certain using the offset from the active cell. But it always throw an error "**Object variable or With block variable not set**". Can anyone point out my mistake and make a correction to it? Thanks in advance.

Here is the code:

```
    *OTHER CODES HERE*      

            Dim offsetter As Range
            offsetter = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Address(False, False) //Error on this line

            With Selection.Validation
                .Delete
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE("&offsetter&",' ','_'))"
                .IgnoreBlank = True
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .InputTitle = ""
                .ErrorTitle = ""
                .InputMessage = ""
                .ErrorMessage = ""
                .ShowInput = True
                .ShowError = True
            End With

     *OTHER CODES HERE*
```

I have updated the code and the mistake that I did was declaring the variable as range, whereas it should be string.

I am now getting a new error "**application-defined or object-defined error**"

```
        *OTHER CODES HERE*      

            Dim offsetter As String
            offsetter = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Address(False, False)

            With Selection.Validation
                .Delete
            //Error on this line [.add]
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE("&offsetter&",' ','_'))"
                .IgnoreBlank = True
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .InputTitle = ""
                .ErrorTitle = ""
                .InputMessage = ""
                .ErrorMessage = ""
                .ShowInput = True
                .ShowError = True
            End With

     *OTHER CODES HERE*
```

Here is the final and working code:

```
            Dim offsetter As String
            offsetter = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Address(False, False)

            With Selection.Validation
                .Delete
                'Application-defined or Object-defined error
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Formula1:="=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(""" _
                & offsetter & ""","" "",""_""),""-"",""_""),""/"",""_""),""("",""""),"")"",""""))"
                .IgnoreBlank = True
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .InputTitle = ""
                .ErrorTitle = ""
                .InputMessage = ""
                .ErrorMessage = ""
                .ShowInput = True
                .ShowError = True
            End With
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: `.delete` deletes the Object. So there is no more object to `.add` something to :) I think `.modify` is what you are looking for

Comment: Use `Dim offsetter As String`. You are assigning it a text-based [Range.Address property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837625.aspx), not setting it to the [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) itself.

Comment: I think he already got that, but forgot to include it in his new code-sample.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do with that [INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd) and [SUBSTITUTE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/substitute-function-2bdd8fb3-d756-4656-8aa4-e871e6578671) combinationas there should be no spaces in that address but the line should double up quotes withinh a quoted string and single ticks are not quotes; e.g. `Formula1:="=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE("""&offsetter&""","" "",""_""))"`

Comment: @Tom  -Thanks. Just caught that in the edited narrative.

Comment: @Jeeped Thanks! I got it work here is the actual line btw: `"=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(""" & offsetter & ""","" "",""_""),""-"",""_""),""/"",""_""),""("",""""),"")"",""""))"`

Comment: Please remove "Solved" from your title and question. You can post the answer on its own, and even accept it. That is the proper indication  for others with a similar question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final and working code I did.

```
        Dim offsetter As String
        offsetter = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Address(False, False)

        With Selection.Validation
            .Delete
            'Application-defined or Object-defined error
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
            Formula1:="=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(""" _
            & offsetter & ""","" "",""_""),""-"",""_""),""/"",""_""),""("",""""),"")"",""""))"
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .InputMessage = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = True
        End With
```

Answer (score 0):

A Validation-object has the following three methods:

`Add`
`Delete`
`Modify`

While `Add` and `Modify` work towards the Validation itself, `Delete` deletes the *entire* object. That's why afterwards you are not able to add a validition or to specify any other properties.

Comment: I tried changing the `.Delete` to `.Modify` but it didn't help me. But thanks anyway for making me understand more about Validation on VBA. Btw, I use delete to clear all validation rule before adding the new formula, just in case there is any.